# Problem about Assasin of module

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I found this problem and I don't understand the solution. I will appreciate your help.
Let $A = \mathbb{Q}[X_1,...,X_n,...], a = (X_1^2,...,X_n^2,...)$ and $ M = A/a$.  Show that $Ass_A (M) = \emptyset $. Why isn't $Ass_A(M) = (X_1,...,X_n,...)$ ?

I'm writing this because the site is giving me this error : "Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:

```
* It does not meet our quality standards.".  This feels verry strange!!!
```

Comment: [Here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/what-can-i-do-when-getting-it-does-not-meet-our-quality-standards)'s an explanation of that error and what you can do to avoid getting it.

Comment: Perhaps because the question repeatedly includes the word "ass" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. $Ass_A(M)$ denotes the set of associated primes of $M$, i.e. the set of prime ideals $\mathfrak p$ of $A$ for which there is an embedding $A/\mathfrak p \hookrightarrow M$.  (Note that in particular that $Ass_A(M)$ is *not* an ideal of $A$ --- unlike the annihilator of $M$, which *is* an ideal of $A$.  This is why the assertion
   $Ass_A(M) = \emptyset$ even makes sense.)
2. A contextual remark: if $M$ is an module over a Noetherian ring, then 
   $Ass_A(M)$ is always non-empty.  The point of problem you are asking about is to show that this can be false for non-Noetherian $A$ (such as the $A$ in your question).
3. If $\mathfrak p$ is an element of $Ass_A(M)$, then (as you implicitly observe in your post) it contains the annihilator $Ann_A(M)$ --- which in your
   case is $(X_1^2,X_2^2,\ldots)$, and hence, being prime, it contains the 
   ideal $(X_1, X_2, \ldots)$.  Thus, to solve the problem, you need to show that
   there is no embedding $\mathbb Q[X_1,\ldots]/(X_1,\ldots) \hookrightarrow M$, 
   that is, that there is no non-zero element of $M$ annihilated by $(X_1,X_2,
   \ldots).$
4. If you don't see how to do this straight away, try thinking about the case
   when $A$ has only finitely many indeterminates, i.e. when $A = \mathbb Q[X_1,
   \ldots,X_n],$ and when $M = A/(X_1^2,\ldots,X_n^2)$.  In this case, by remark 2
   above, it must be possible to find a non-zero element of $M$ which *is*
   annihilated by $(X_1,X_2,\ldots, X_n)$.  Find this element explicitly.  Once
   you have found it, look at it, and see why you *can't* construct an analogous element in the case of infinitely many variables.

Answer (score 0):

The annihilator of a module $M$ over a ring $A$ is the set of elements $a$ in $A$ such that $aM=0$. This is an ideal of $A$ usually denoted by $\textrm{Ann}_A(M)$ and I think this is what you mean by assasin. In this case, the annihilator of $M$ over $A$ is the zero ideal because if $X_i X_{i+1} \neq 0$ in $M$ for every $i \geq 1$.

If you actually mean the set of associated primes of $M$ over $A$ I think it works as follows.  The ring $A/a$ has precisely one (prime) ideal: the image of $(X_1,X_2,\ldots)$ in $A/a$. Now, the annihilator of this submodule is just zero. This is a prime ideal of $A$ and thus, the set of associated primes should be a singleton.

Maybe I'm wrong?